# Deku's Physique

Tags: my-hero-academia

Midoriya trained for 10 months to build his body and after his training he was jacked [Lean muscular build] right, so why does he look off model/half of his size/skinny from entrance exam till the end of sports festival?
All other characters are designed well except him In the USJ arc, all the characters look great but Midoriya looks so skinny.
In the Hero Killer arc, he again has the same physique as the one in the Beach scene like literally the same.

Is this just due the Art style changes by the author/artist in both Anime and Manga or are there any reasons for him to be skinny after that beach scene?

Comment: I only just started My Hero Academia, so can't really provide a full answer, but remember that All Might said that Deku rushed the training process in order to meet his deadline. As I see it, the art style is a representation of Deku still adapting to his new muscle body and quirk

Comment: I believe what all might said was related to how muh % of One for All, Deku could use since it  was never tested until the Zero Point robot scene. As for the muscle he trained for 10 months and he should've been adapted to that build but he went from that build to skinny in entire season 1 as if he never did that 10 month training. All of a sudden in the Hero killer arc in season 2 he has the exact same build he had in  the Season 1 beach scene.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that it's implied that Midoria is not well endowed, athletically speaking.

All Might was able to use One For All at 100% immediately after receiving it, though it was much weaker back then, and Bakugo was able to use One For All at 100% when he got it temporarily against Nine.

I think there are a couple other points that support this idea as well. For example, a combat quirk isn't required to be a formidable fighter, take Sir Nighteye for example. But Midoria never seemed to even consider training that way, even though he must have known it was possible, so he instead focused on the intellectual aspect of hero work, because he knew that he didn't have the physical capacity for combat.

Now, this is an anime, so despite his physical limitations, he's able to continue to train and get stronger regardless, but I'd argue that there's plenty of evidence that he has some sort of physiological disorder that's inhibiting his muscle growth.

Answer (score 0):

Well my guess for why he would look skinny is all because of character and development of that character, What I mean is, Deku or Izuku mydoria was "born" quirkless and in the MHA universe that means your theoretically very weak or frail compared to others with quirks. So in this case the reason he may look small or weak even though he is very built muscle-wise is probably all because of character plot or development.

Hope that answers your question!

(The credibility of this answer is based on watching the anime many times and being very familiar with the way the plot and development work)

Comment: I agree he was born quirkless and was initially skinny but he trained his body and was well built and muscular. He is weak when it comes to handling his quirk compared to others.The other characters know the limit they can use. From what i understood he is supposed to be able to use 5% right after the training in the beach, but since he doesn't know how to regulate the power, he could only use either 0 or 100% and as result he wrecks himself. He only learns how to use his quirk when he started to train with Grand Torino and he all of sudden looks muscular exactly like how he was in chapter 2.

Comment: How is making him look skinny when his physically well built, useful for plot and character development . That defeats the purpose of him training to build his body. For plot purpose he is already weak since he can't use his quirk effectively without breaking himself.

Comment: Also in Quirk Apprehension test arc which i think is in chapter 5, the characters taller than him look bigger than him in size where as the characters shorter than him look smaller than him in size.

Answer (score 0):

I think I could be that, or it could be the fact that his body was not meant for his power and he also took a lot damage from it and it put a lot of physical strain on his body so he was constantly having to visit recovery girl. And he was born without a power so his body would go through physical changes to be able to handle One for all